# Mage.exe problems when run from script file

Tags: ant, clickonce, mage

I am in the process of automating a ClickOnce deployment of a product. I am using ANT for a build script and I am running into a problem that I cannot find an answer to. I can build my project and copy the needed files (EXEs, DLLs, etc.) to a staging directory. I can open the command prompt and manually run mage.exe and generate and sign both the application and deployment manifest. This gives me a working deployment that will install and run. The problem comes when I try to automate this with an ANT script. I compile the product and copy it just fine. When it comes to creating the application manifest I get the following error for every file:

Warning MSB3178: Assembly {assemblyName} is incorrectly specified as a file.

Keep in mind that the exact same mage command is used, but when I run it from a script I get this warning, which is really an error in the end. Because of this error that application manifest file is invalid and my product won't install on a users machine. Once again, if I manually type the same command in the command prompt then it works and my deployment is great, but from my script it is not working. All of the properties are verified to be correct and all paths are also correct. I have also tried to run the commands with all hardcoded values (no properties) and the errors persist.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<target name="foo">
  <exec executable='${mage}'>
    <arg line='-New Application 
              -Processor x86 
              -ToFile 'D:\BuildSynch\ClickOnce\TabletMPE\1.0.0.0\TabletMPE.exe.manifest' 
              -name 'TabletMPE'
              -Version 1.0.0.0 
              -FromDirectory '1.0.0.0'"/>
</exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code certainly does not seem correct to me. I would try this :

```
<exec executable='${mage}'>
    <arg line='-New "Application" -Processor "x86" -ToFile "D:\BuildSynch\ClickOnce\TabletMPE\1.0.0.0\TabletMPE.exe.manifest" -name "TabletMPE" -Version "1.0.0.0" -FromDirectory "1.0.0.0"'/>
</exec>
```

In addition you should try to use the `<arg value=""/>` as it is [**highly** recommended](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg) in the ant manual.